# AWS - EC2 package to store giant sparse matrix in Rstudio

Tags: r, amazon-ec2, rstudio-server

I am creating a list named `rte` in R with `350` elements, each of them is a large-scale, sparse matrix (entries are only `0` or `1`) with row x column = `300+ x  320,000+`. The code, which is put on `Amazon Web Server - EC2` with instance type `m5.24xlarge` to run, works perfectly fine, but `Rstudio Server` automatically aborts after the `8th iteration`.

**Question:** Is the only option for me to go through all `350` iterations, create and save each of those matrices successfully, is to utilize the most powerful instance (`x1.32xlarge`) on AWS - EC2? (https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2016/05/now-available-x1-instances-the-largest-amazon-ec2-memory-optimized-instance-with-2-tb-of-memory/) 
Given that I still need to save the list in the `workspace` of `Rstudio` since for each of the `matrix element`, as I will perform some algebraic manipulations with each of them.

```
rte_m <- vector("list", length(unique(d_zone_ON$Date)))
inx_big = 0
for(j in unique(d_zone_ON$Date)){
  inx_row <- sum(d_zone_ON$Date== j)
  inx_big <- inx_big+1
  rte_m[[inx_big]] <- data.frame(matrix(0, nrow = inx_row, ncol = inx_row*(inx_row+1)/2))
  lb <- min(which(d_zone_ON$Date == j)) 
  ub <- max(which(d_zone_ON$Date == j)) 
  for(i in lb:ub){
    if(i==lb){
       rte_m[[inx_big]][1,1:(ub-lb)] = 1; 
    }
    else if(i<ub && i> lb){
      rte_m[[inx_big]][i-lb+1, ((i-lb)*(ub-lb)-(i-lb+1)*(i-lb-2)/2):((i-lb+1)*(ub-lb)-(i-lb+1)*(i-lb)/2)] = 1; 
    } else {rte_m[[inx_big]][ub-lb+1, ] = 0} 
  }
}
```

[Link to data frame d_zone_ON](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1MXvSSFP2sgud74LddhOMJiNX6H2uKZi8)